# Contractibility of space of positive definite matrices of determinant 1

Tags: matrices, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, positive-definite

I know (of course) how to prove that the space ${\mathcal P}$ of all positive definite, symmetric matrices is contractible: the homotopy $H(t,P)=tE_n+(1-t)P$ uniformly moves all $P$ to $E_n$ through positive definite, symmetric matrices.

Now restrict to ${\mathcal P}_1$, that is, matrices in ${\mathcal P}$ of determinant $1$. The above homotopy does not preserve the property of having determinant $1$.

Is there some elegant way of proving that ${\mathcal P}_1$ is contractible?

Comment: What's $E_n$? Maybe could you normalize by $\sqrt[n]{\text{det}P}?$

Answer (score 3):

Let $P'$ be the space of positive definite symmetric matrices with trace $1$. Since it is the intersection of $P$ with an affine space, it is still convex, hence contractible. Now the map from $P_1$ to $P'$ where you divide by trace is a homeomorphism.